# Why is 50 Ω often chosen as the input impedance of antennas, whereas the free space impedance is 377 Ω?

Tags: antenna, impedance-matching, high-frequency

In order to efficiently deliver power to a different part of a circuit without reflection, the impedances of all circuit elements need to be matched. Free space can be regarded as a further element, since a transmitting antenna eventually should radiate all power from the transmission line into it.

Now, if the impedances in the transmission line and in the antenna are matched at 50 Ω, but the impedance of free space is 377 Ω, won't there be a impedance mismatch and consequently a less-than-optimal radiation from the antenna?

[image]

As far as I gathered from literature and discussions online, the antenna acts as an impedance transformer between the feed line and free space. The argument goes: no power from the feed line is reflected and must go to the antenna. The antenna can be assumed to be resonant and therefore radiates all its power into free space (disregarding heat losses, etc.). This means that there is no reflected power between antenna and free space, and the transition between antenna and free space is therefore matched.

The same should be true in the reverse direction for a receiving antenna (Reciprocity Principle): a wave in free space (\$Z_0\$) impinges onto an antenna, and the received power is fed into the transmission line (again through impedance transformation). At least in one paper (Devi et al., Design of a wideband 377 Ω E-shaped patch antenna for RF energy harvesting, Microwave and Optical Letters (2012) Vol. 54, No. 3, 10.1002/mop.26607) it was mentioned that a 377 Ω antenna with a separate circuit to match it to 50 Ω was used to "achieve a wide impedance bandwidth" with a high power level. If the antenna normally is already the impedance transformer, what is the matching circuit needed for then? Or alternatively, under what circumstances is the antenna not also the impedance transformer?

Some helpful sources and discussions I found:

- Klaus Kark, Antenne und Strahlungsfelder (in German)
- Impedance Matching ([http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~majewski/nqr/reference2015/nqr_detection_educational/Impedance_matching_networks.pdf](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/%7Emajewski/nqr/reference2015/nqr_detection_educational/Impedance_matching_networks.pdf))
- Forum discussion that mentions impedance transformation for an inverted-F antenna (http://www.antenna-theory.com/phpbb2/viewtopic.php?t=776&sid=dede0d4127170d16cc3a583ab0929f3e)
- Some general notes about antennas (http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/862.16/notes/antennas.pdf)

Comment: For TV I see more often 75Ω and you need to consider the impedance of the feedline, and then you look up where the best power transfer lies (wikipedia has a chart) and other parameters and then you find a compromise

Comment: In short: 50 ohms is nice compromise between power transmission towards the antenna and dielectric losses inside cables we can make easily. It's nice to be able to make stuff easily.

Comment: "My question to this is: how does a single wire, (1/4 or 1/2 wavelength long) convert form 50 to 377?" - you mean how does the **antenna** transform from 50 to 377 Ohms? If that is what you want to know then it should be in your question. Otherwise the answer is simply "because that is the impedance of that type of antenna".

Comment: This seems to be in contradiction to @Curd's answer. Does an antenna act as a impedance transformer (50 to 377Ω) or do we just chose 50Ω because the cables and transmitters are easier to build that way and we just accept the radiation losses?

Comment: Both is true. That's no contradiction. Anennas act as transmores **and** you can build them in ways to transform to high or low impedance depending on the antenna design. The same is true for amplifiers or transmission lines.

Comment: Ah, I see. Assuming some transmission line with 377Ω works well at some frequency - do we still use a dipole then to 'couple' to free space? In such a case, the antenna doesn't need to match anything then as it seems.

Comment: @ahemmetter: ...because it is just a transmission line. It simply does not have the special property of antennas: efficiently transmitting energy to/picking energy up from space. Just matching impedance is not all you need.

Comment: https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/why-fifty-ohms

Comment: Historical note: from what I recall, the lowest loss coax cables are in the 63 ohm region; this lowest-loss is important for long coax runs between the top of ships-masts-antennas and the radio room. And these were air-filled coaxes, with glass-bead spacers between center and shield, for low losses. If you fill this same coax-cable with polyethylene, you now has a 50 ohm coax.

Comment: Similar wuestion was asked here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/395847/125197

Comment: @user1234 It seems that questions asks about matching a feed line to a load (antenna). My question was about matching the antenna to free space.

Comment: Btw it is resistive only if it is in far field

Comment: @user1234 "The 37 ohms is the radiation resistance and the antenna transforms the natural impedance of free space (377 ohms) to 37 ohms [...]". It seems it's just reformulating roughly what was mentioned in the answers here already. The radiation resistance is not 377 Ohm; the radiation resistance is one part of the input impedance (the rest being losses), so it's something like 73 Ohm for a half wave dipole or 37 for a quarter wave dipole

Comment: @user1234 That about the far field might actually be an important point. Since the phase angle between fields in the near field is different from the far field, it seems also the impedance would be different, and maybe "transforms itself" while moving into the far field.

Comment: Antenna current take it I. Far field is pure resl so Prad=1/2 I^2 Rrad. Rrad= 2 pi/3 nu (L/lambda)^2 where nu is 120 pi. You need to read Friis transmission equation. It is a model assuming far field is not reactive derived from radiated power

Comment: 377 comes from 120 pi

Comment: @user1234 Sure, I know where \$Z_0\$ and radiation resistance come from, that's not the issue. As you said yourself, \$R_{rad}\$ depends on the antenna length. Expanded it is something like  \$R_{rad} = 197.3 \Omega \cdot (l/\lambda)^2 (1 + 1.316 \cdot (l/\lambda)^2 + ...)\$. Plugging in \$l = 0.5\$ for the half wave dipole approaches 73 instead of 377 Ohm.

Comment: Yes and as far as I understand that Rrad is part of tuning proccess I mean included in impedance matching

Comment: See my new answer: the free-space impedance is for fields and has no relation to impedances defined for currents and voltages (such as line impedance, resistance). It is only "by accident" that it has the same unit (ohms)

Comment: Ah, free space has no reflections.  I guess you don't believe in radar.

Comment: So what if there is a mismatch?  Enough signal usually leaks through to do the job.  If you happen to have a 377 ohm load, you can use a transformer.  There are two kinds of transformers in common use: coils with shared flux, and transmission line arrangements (that are limited to a single frequency).   You will be able to design these if you learn to work with Smith charts.

Comment: " free space. The argument goes: no power from the feed line is reflected and must go to the antenna. The antenna can be assumed to be resonant and therefore radiates all its power into free space (disregarding heat losses etc)." - if you disregard resistive losses, an antenna radiates all of the applied power, regardless of its complex impedance (i.e. resonant or not).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_impedance#50_%CE%A9_and_75_%CE%A9

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The input impedance of certain devices/circuits (transformers) does not neccessarily need to match their output impedance.

Consider a 50Ω (or whatever impedance) antenna as transformer that transforms 50Ω (wire side) to 377Ω (space side).

The impedance of the antenna is not (only) given by the impedance of free space but (also) by the way it is constructed.

So the antenna **does** match the impedance of free space (on one side); and ideally also the impedance of the circuit (on the other side).
Since the space side's impedance is always the same (for all kinds of antennas operated in vacuum or air), it doesn't need to be mentioned.
Only the wire side is what you need and can care about.

The reason 50Ω or 75Ω or 300Ω or ... is choosen as antenna impedances is because of practical reasons to construct particular antennas/transmission lines/amplifiers with that impedance.

A possible ansatz for calculating the radiation resistance \$R\$ of an antenna is:

Find an answer to the question: 
"How much power \$P\$ (average over one period) is radiated if a sinusoidal signal of given voltage (or current) amplitude \$V_0\$ (or \$I_0\$) is applied to the antenna?"

Then you get 
\$R = \frac{V_0^2}{2P}\$ (or \$=\frac{2P}{I_0^2}\$)

You get radiated power \$P\$ by integrating the Poynting vector \$\mathbf{S}\$ (=radiated power per area) over the sphere enclosing the antenna.

The Poynting vector is \$\mathbf{S} = \frac{1}{\mu_0} \mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B}\$ where \$\mathbf{E}\$ and \$\mathbf{B}\$ are electric/magnetic fields caused by the voltages and currents in your antenna.

You can find an example for such a calculation in the Wikipedia acticle about "Dipole antenna", in  paragraph [Short Dipole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna#Short_dipole).

Comment: My question to this is: how does a single wire, (1/4 or 1/2 wavelength long) convert form 50 to 377? There isn't an obvious 2:15 ratio there.

Comment: "Just" apply Maxwell's equations to your antenna geometry and you will find, that it will turn out that it does (not exactly but about). Your expectation to immediately "see" the 50/377 ratio in wire or wave length ratios is not justified; but you will get the result if you do the integrations etc.

Comment: I'd appreciate to see at least the ansatz to this calculation for a dipole antenna. It's not trivial to see where the impedances appear in such a case and how Maxwell's equations can be applied to find them. Would it be possible to add this to the answer or link to an article explaining it?

Comment: At best you are arguing that the feedpoint impedance is what it is because that is what works.  That's not an answer.  An answer would explain *why* the feedpoint impedance is what it is.  And no, it isn't too match the feedline, if anything the other way around, the feedline is designed with the antenna impedance as one of the goals.

Comment: Yes, it's not trivial to see. Nobody said it would be. Maybe I can find a simple example... not within the next few hours however.

Comment: @Chris Straton: I made clear that is wrong to assume that a good antenna should have 377Ohm impedance (of course at the feed point; anything else doesn't make sense). I did give an answer (high level) to the "Why?". and even more details in the comment and if I have time I will give expand my answer, maybe with some formulas... (what do you expect within a few minutes?)

Comment: @ahemmetter: I don't have access to it right now but I think Jackson's "Classical Electrodynamics" could have some examples of that kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks for adding the ansatz. So, to clarify: the input impedance (especially the radiation resistance \$R\$) is the impedance 'seen' by the transmission line, whereas power radiated into free space depends on the free space impedance in the Poynting vector \$S = \frac{E^2}{Z_0}\$. And the antenna just transforms between both impedances. Is that more or less correct?

Comment: @ahemmetter: yes, I think that properly sums it up.

Comment: @Curd Looking at the fields is the way to go, see my answer. wave impedances and resistances have no relation at all, and, thus, neither do 50 Ohm and 377 Ohm.

Comment: @Faekynn: I wouldn't say they have relation because: suppose you submerge a 50Ω (air) antenna in water (or an other medium) its radiation resistance would change very well.

Comment: @curd i do not completely agree. In your ex., the permittivity changes and has an effect on both kinds of impedances. But the effects are not related: the relation is not predictable. Changing the permittivity has a defined effect on the wave imp. But the rad. resistance effect is not clear but depends on the antenna geometry. Thus, my statement still is that input/line impedances and wave impedances are not related at all. However, changing the physical conditions can or cannot affect both (see my example of the coacial cable where the wave impedance is *not* changed by changing the geometry)

Comment: Your radiation resistance description is a little loose. The current in the equation must be the maximum effective current causing the radiation not simply the applied current. The distinction becomes important as the feedpoint is moved on the radiating antenna element. On a half wave antenna the feedpoint current changes but the radiation resistance does not. On other antenna geometries, changing the feedpoint location changes the maximum effective radiating current and thus the radiation resistance.

Comment: I should also add that your radiation resistance formula is only valid for a Hertzian dipole where it is assumed that the current drops off linearly towards the ends (thus the reason to divide maximum current by 2 to obtain average current). As a counter example, in a 1/2 wave dipole, the current drops off by cos(2πz/λ). Thus your formula would predict a radiation resistance of ~50 ohms for a 1/2 wave dipole while in fact it is 73 ohms.

Comment: @Glenn W9IQ: I'm not sure if I know what you mean by "my radiation resistance formula". If you mean  \$R = 2P/I_0\$: The factor 1/2 is nothing but the squared factor for converting amplitude (=max. value) to effective value (because average power over one period is asked for) of a sinusoidal signal. It is exact if a sinusoidal signal is fed into the antenna. This formula as well as the Poynting vector formula are exact and valid in general; no approximations, idealizations or restrictions (besides assuming a sinusoidal signal). I don't see any other formulas in my posting.

Comment: @Glenn W9IQ: Approximations might come into play when E and B are expressed in terms of current/voltage; but I didn't do that in my posting. The linked Wikipedia article does that (but that's not "my formula"). If you mean that: please discuss it there. I linked it just as an example showing how my **ansatz** can be used.

Comment: So do you use RMS or peak (I and V) in your formula?

Comment: @Glenn W9IQ: I wrote: "voltage (or current) **amplitude** \$V_0\$ (or \$I_0\$)". Amplitude means peak.

Answer (score 22):

All the answers name some valid points, but they fail to really answer the question which I want to repeat for clarity:

`Why is 50 Ω often chosen as the input impedance of antennas, whereas the free space impedance is 377 Ω?`

### The Short & Simple Answer

These two impedances have no relation at all. They describe different physical phenomena: the antenna input impedance is not related to the 377 Ω free-space impedance.
It is only *by accident* that the unit of both terms is the same (i,e., Ohms).
Furthermore, 50 Ω is just a common value for characteristic impedances of transmission lines etc., see the other answers.

Basically, the input impedance of an antenna, any other resistance or reactance, and characteristic impedances are circuit-level descriptions for handling voltages and currents, while the free space wave impedance is for describing electric and magnetic fields. In particular, the (real-valued) 50 Ω input impedance means if you apply 50 V of voltage at the antenna feed, 1 A current will flow trough the antenna feed point.
The free-space impedance has no relation to any antenna or material configuration. It describes the ratio of electric and magnetic fields in a propagating plane wave, which is approximatly obtained in an infinite distance to a radiating antenna.

### The Longer Answer

The first impedance mentioned in the question is the input impedance of the antenna, which is a sum of radiation resistance, loss resistance and reactive components which are described as the imaginary part. It is related to currents \$I\$ and voltages \$V\$ *at the feeding pont* on a circuit-description level, i.e.,
$$R = \frac{V}{I}\,.$$
Changing the feeding point of the antenna, the value of this radiation resistance might change (this fact is employed e.g. for the matching of inset fed microstrip patch antennas). The radiated fields, however, stay basically the same.

This impedance \$R\$ of the radiation resistance is the same kind as of a resistor or the transmission line characteristic impedance of coaxial lines or microstrip lines, since these are also defined via voltages and currents.

The radiation resistance is not a real resistance, it is just a model for the radiation case (i.e., operating the antenna to transmit power), where power gets lost from the circuit point of view since it is radiated away. (On a related note: using this resistance for the receive case is misleading, since there occurs no loss in the radation resistance. It is still important for matching, though.)

The second impedance is a wave impedance of the fields, which describes the ratios of electric (\$E\$) and magnetic (\$H\$) fields. The free-space impedance, for instance is given as
$$ Z_{0,\mathrm{free\,space}} = \frac{E}{H} = \pi 119,9169832\,\Omega\approx377\,\Omega\,.$$
(This exact value was used before 2019, see [Wikipedia on the free-space impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_of_free_space))
We can immediately see that fields and voltages have a relation that might change with geometry etc, or there might be no unique definition of voltages (e.g., in a hollow waveguide).

To make this lack of relation of these kinds of impedances more clear, an example might help.
[In the very simple case of the TEM wave inside of a coaxial cable,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_cable#Derived_electrical_parameters) we know how to calculate the characteristic impedance the coaxial cable based on the geometry as
$$Z_{0,\mathrm{coax}}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_0}}\ln\frac{r_{\mathrm{outer}}}{r_{\mathrm{inner}}}\,,$$
if we assume that the filling material is vacuum.
This is a characteristic impedance (of the transmission line) for the currents and voltages of this line, and this is the kind of impedance which should be matched to the input impedance of an antenna.

[However, having a look at the fields inside the cable,](http://www.hep.princeton.edu/%7Emcdonald/examples/coax_potential.pdf) we find that the electric field has only the radial component (exact values are irrelevant in this context)
$$E_r \propto \frac{1}{r \ln(r_{\mathrm{inner}}/r_{\mathrm{outer}})} \,.$$
More interestingly, the \$B\$ field has only a \$\phi\$-component which is a scaled version of the electric radial field
$$B_\phi = \frac{k}{\omega}E_r=\frac{1}{c}E_r\,,$$
where \$c\$ is the speed of light, which is from free space (!) because the medium inside is free space.
By using
$$ B = \mu H\,,$$
we finally know the phi-component of the magnetic field as
$$H_\phi =\frac{\sqrt{\epsilon}}{\sqrt{\mu}}E_r=Z_{0,\mathrm{free\,space}}E_r\,,$$
Therefore, the ratio of electric and magnetic fields is constant and only medium dependent; however, it does not depend on the geometry of the cable.

For free space inside the coaxial cable, the wave impedance is always approximately 377 Ω, while the characteristic impedance is geometry-dependent and can take any possible value from almost zero to extremely large values.

### Conclusion & Final Remarks

If we look again at the example of the coaxial cable and leave it open at the end, achieving a characteristic impedance of ~377 Ω does not relate to anything about the fields. Any coaxial cable filled with air has a wave impedance of ~377 Ω, but this does not at all help to make the open piece of coaxial cable a good antenna. Therefore, a good definition of antenna does not relate at all to impedances, but reads

`An antenna is a transducer from a guided wave to an unguided wave.`

Comment: "The first impedance mentioned in the question is the input impedance of the antenna, which is a sum of radiation resistance and losses." is not a correct statement. The input impedance of the antenna may also consist of a non-real component. Radiation resistance and efficiency losses are only real (purely resistive) terms. Many common antennas (including a strict definition of a 1/2 wavelength antenna) have a reactive impedance component.

Comment: I should note that strictly speaking, the real part of antenna input impedance and the radiation resistance of the antenna can be quite different. A classic example is a non-center fed, 1/2 wavelength, dipole antenna.

Comment: "If we look again at the example of the coaxial cable and leave it open at the end, achieving a line impedance of ~377 Ω does not relate to anything about the fields. " It also is not the "line impedance" nor the input impedance nor the characteristic impedance.

Comment: @GlennW9IQ about the first comment: you are right, I forgot to mention the reactive input impedance parts.

Comment: 2nd comment: this probably depends on how you define the radiation resistance. for me, the radiation resistance just changes in the non-center fed case and still is equal to the real part of the antenna input impedance, but now for a different kind of antenna

Comment: 3rd comment: what I mean by line impedance is the ratio of voltage and current of a wave on the transmission line. The point is that 377 is not a special value, as it might be suggested by the paper referenced in the question. Somehow, I do not really understand what you wanted to express? it would be helpful for me if you could explain it more...

Comment: When you create your own definitions for well practiced terms, such as radiation resistance, you will have problems effectively communicating. Your definition won't work when you calculate antenna efficiency, for example.

Comment: The common terms for transmission lines, relative to impedance, are characteristic impedance and input impedance. "Line impedance" is an ambiguous term.

Comment: "The first impedance mentioned in the question is the input impedance of the antenna, which is a sum of radiation resistance, loss resistance and reactive components" is not a correct statement. Radiation resistance is often not equal to Re(Z) for an ideal antenna.

Comment: For example, an ideal 1/2 wavelength element in free space has a radiation resistance of ~73 ohms. But, depending on where the antenna is fed, the Re(Z)  can vary from 73 ohms to >3,000 ohms. This is due to the voltage and current standing waves on the antenna and their differing relative phases along the length of the antenna.

Comment: @GlennW9IQ I do not create my own definitions. It is clear that the radiation resistance changes with geometrical changes or with frequency. If you transfer the example of the half-wavelength dipole to different scenarios (I mentioned the inset-fed patch antenna) the fact of a changing radiation resistance is even used in a positive way for matching to the desired input impedance!

Comment: Taking the standard half-wavelength dipole, the radiation resistance of 73 Ohm is only valid for a feed in the center. If you feed at a different point, you *will* have to match to a different resistance for a good radiation efficiency, so it makes sense (with such a different geometry) to have a different radiation resistance (i.e., a different model for a different antenna)

Comment: for the impedance term, you are right. I changed it to characteristic

Comment: The radiation resistance and the radiation pattern does not change on a 1/2 wavelength dipole when you keep the frequency the same and change only the feedpoint. The feedpoint impedance does change under these conditions. For a center fed arrangement the feedpoint impedance is ~ 73 ohms and fed 1/3 from the end the impedance is ~112-j13 ohms. For a given power level, the current levels and the current distribution does not change between the two scenarios. That is a working example of what is wrong with saying that Radiation Resistance = Re(Z).

Comment: If you leave a coaxial cable "open at the end", the impedance is not simply 377 ohms. Under this condition, the voltage reflection coefficient is 1 and the current reflection coefficient is -1. The input impedance of the coax is now a factor of the loss and the electrical length of the coax. The characteristic impedance does not change under any application circumstance.

Comment: WHat is the free space impedance when air is saturated with 100% humidity with some % of moisture content at Dk=80? How about when pouring rain?  Does Antenna input impedance change in the rain?

Answer (score 8):

50 ohms is a convention. It's much more convenient if a room full of equipment all uses the same impedance.

Why is it the convention? Because coax is popular, and because 50 ohms is a good value for coax impedance, and it's a nice round number.

Why is it a good value for coax? The impedance of coax is a function of the ratio of the diameters of the shield and center conductor, and the dielectric material used:

$$ Z_0 = {138 \over \sqrt{\epsilon}} \log_{10}\left(D\over d\right) $$

Or rearranged algebraically:

$$ {D \over d} = 10^{\sqrt{\epsilon} Z_0 / 138} $$

where:

- \$Z_0\$ is the characteristic impedance of the coax
- \$\epsilon\$ is the dielectric constant (air is 1, [PTFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene) is 2.1)
- \$D\$ is the diameter of the inside surface of the shield
- \$d\$ is the diameter of the outside surface of the center conductor

As the characteristic impedance increases, the center conductor must become smaller if the shield geometry and dielectric material remain constant. For \$Z_0 = 377\:\Omega \$, and PFTE dielectric:

$$ {D \over d} = 10^{\sqrt{2.1}\ 377 / 138} = 9097 $$

So for a coax cable with an outside diameter of 10 mm (RG-8, LMR-400, etc are approximately this size), the center conductor would have to be 10 mm / 9097 = 1.10 *micro*meters. That's impossibly fine: if it could even be manufactured with copper it would be extremely fragile. Additionally loss would be very high due to the high resistance.

On the other hand, the same calculation with \$Z_0 = 50\:\Omega \$ yields an inner conductor of approximately 3 mm, or 9 gauge wire. Easily manufactured, mechanically robust, and with sufficient surface area to result in acceptably low loss.

OK, so 50 ohms is a convention because it works for coax. But what about free space, which we can't change? Is that a problem?

Not really. Antennas are impedance transformers. A resonant wire dipole is a very easy to construct antenna, and it has a feedpoint impedance of 70 ohms, not 377.

It's not such a foreign concept. Air and other materials also have an *acoustic* impedance, which is the ratio of pressure to volume flow. It's analogous to electrical impedance which is the ratio of voltage to current. Somewhere in your house you probably have a speaker (perhaps a subwoofer) with a horn on it: that horn is there to take the very low acoustic impedance of air and transform it to something higher to better match the driver.

An antenna serves the same function, but for electric waves. The free space into which the antenna radiates has a fixed 377 ohm impedance, but the impedance at the other end depends on the geometry of the antenna. Previously mentioned, a resonant dipole has an impedance of 70 ohms. But bending that dipole so it forms a "V" instead of a straight line will decrease that impedance. A [monopole antenna](http://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/monopole.php) has half the impedance of the antenna: 35 ohms. A [folded dipole](http://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/foldeddipole.php) has four times the impedance of the simple dipole: 280 ohms.

More complex antenna geometries can result in any feedpoint impedance you like, so while it would be technically possible to design an antenna with a feedpoint impedance of 377 ohms, but you wouldn't want to use it with coax for the reasons above. But perhaps [twin-lead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin-lead) would work, though there wouldn't be any particular advantage to 377 ohm twin-lead.

At the end of the day, the antenna's job by definition is to convert a wave in one medium (free space) into a wave in another medium (a feedline). The two don't usually have the same characteristic impedance and so an antenna must be an impedance transformer to do the job efficiently. Most antennas transform to 50 ohms because most people want to use 50 ohm coax feedlines.

Comment: Good answer. But the diameter on the inside surface of the shield of LMR-400 is 0.285" (7.2 mm). 10 mm is the diameter over the outer jacket. That makes your point even better, as now your conductor has to have a diameter of 8 µm (or about 80 AWG).

Comment: True, I should have said it's an approximation.

Comment: It is true as you state in your answer `there wouldn't be any particular advantage to 377 ohm twin-lead.` The reason is missing which I give in my answer: 377 Ohm line impedance or resistance is a ratio of voltage and current, whereas the 377 Ohm free space wave impedance is a ratio of electric and magnetic fields. So just same unit, but no relation.

Comment: @Faekynn It's the ratio of electric and magnetic fields in a transmission line also, if one considers the fields that exist between the conductors in the transmission line.

Comment: yes that is correct but there the difference persists. The wave impedance of a coaxial cable filled with air is ~377 Ohm, but the line impedance is something with logarithm (diameters). So, also for the transmission line there are these two unrelated impedances. I tried to explain this in my answer.

Comment: I believe the primary reason for 50 ohm coax, is that for solid PE dielectric, it provides the lowest loss at ~52 ohms. For foamed PE, ~64 ohms is the lowest loss.

Comment: Do Zo of air change with Rain? If so , how much?

Answer (score 2):

This question is a good example of over interpreting electrical engineering rules that were devised to make the physics more manageable in practical contexts.  Impedance simply isn't that important.

The energy of a radio wave is embodied in the electric and magnetic fields distributed in a spatial volume.  Maxwell's equations establish requirements for the relationships among those fields, and the homogenous equations imply that a disturbance from equilibrium will propagate.  The latter is evident from the fact that the wave equation is easily derived from the fundamental equations.

In the wave equation there is an implied velocity of propagation that is the reciprocal of the square root of the product of the magnetic permeability and electric permittivity of the medium of propagation.

The square root of the quotient of those two quantities has units of impedance, and when the medium in question is a vacuum or air, it is called the 'radiation impedance of free space'.

This phrase refers to the ease (or difficulty) of establishing a non-equilibrium electro-magnetic disturbance.  Loosely, it is a measure of the capacity of a volume of the medium to store energy in electro-magnetic form.  More energy requires more volume or you risk non-linear breakdown.  Very loosely, we are quantifying how hard it is to push energy into the system.

In a transmission line, say an old fashioned twin lead, we have a similar situation with different boundary conditions.  The energy in the line is stored (transiently) in the oscillating electric field between conductors and the oscillating magnetic field about the conductors.  This energy can propagate in two directions.  If you have equal amounts of energy propagating in both directions, you have resonance or a standing wave.  If you have matched terminations, energy leaves the line when it gets to the end and does not reflect or propagate back.  It is important to understand that the power is transmitted in the *insulator*, **not** the *conductors*.  The conductors are present only to provide boundary conditions, and the charge carriers in the conductors oscillate essentially in place, providing terminals for electric fields, and coupling the electric and magnetic fields.  These ideas apply equally well to coaxial lines, but it is easier to visualize in a twin lead.

Like free space, a transmission line has a characteristic impedance that is a measure of its capacity to temporarily store energy distributed along its length.  This impedance is dependent upon the geometry of the conductors (boundary conditions) and the relative permeability and permittivity of the materials from which the line is fabricated.  Likewise, there is a characteristic propagation velocity that is typically a substantial fraction of the velocity of light in a vacuum.

The requirement for 'matching' impedances arises from the physics of wave reflection.  Obviously any reflected energy is not propagated out of the system.  A match eliminates reflected energy.  It is important to realize that broadband matches are difficult.  Matches are typically tuned to the specific design frequency of the system, and out of band signals may exhibit significant reflections.

In a resonant feed line, this fact is exploited by driving the line at its resonant frequency.  At resonance, the line impedance is purely resistive.  The difficulty is, you need to control the feed line length precisely, and it is only useful at its resonant frequency.

A more practical compromise is to match impedance.  Then the feed line may be any reasonable length, and the signal may be a composition of many frequencies, or many independent signals, within the limitations of the bandwidth of the match.

A simple antenna like a dipole is operated at resonance.  It is a resonant feedline.  It therefore presents a purely resistive characteristic impedance (dependent on geometry and physics) at its design frequency.  A line matched to that impedance will deliver all of its energy to the antenna.  The antenna, being a resonant feedline, in turn delivers all of its energy to the next system, which is typically free space.  It does this because at its design frequency, there is no reactive impedance.  If you need to push more energy, you need to drive the antenna harder, which raises the peak voltages and currents in the antenna, which increases the amount of energy pushed out into free space during a given cycle.  Obviously there are limitations imposed by non-linear breakdown.

A broadband antenna is really just a lossy feedline.  Within its design bandwidth, all energy is radiated by the time an oscillation reaches the end of the feedline.  Such antennas typically embody conical geometry in some form, with the low frequency limit set by the base of the cone and the high frequency limit set by practal limits on the pointiness of the cone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If we take the optical analog to the feed line/antenna/free space system, we can consider different slabs of transparent media with different refractive indices. Lets assume the first interface is matched and provides no reflection: the energy is in the second ("antenna") medium and forms a standing wave (for example a Fabry-Perot resonance). Eventually of course the energy in the cavity is radiated into the third medium (free space). What would change if the antenna medium and free space medium have the same \$n\$? There is no  cavity and all radiation is transmitted

Comment: Note: [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) is supported here. Using it might make your answer clearer.

Comment: What is your definition of a "resonant feedline"? "At resonance, the line impedance is purely resistive." cannot be the case since any real transmission line (i.e. with loss) must have a reactive component as part of the characteristic impedance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing my first steps in antenna and RF field. I was learning about Antenna Impedance when I found this question and I will try to answer it. Hopefully I have understood the question! Sorry if the answer looks stupid, I'm just a "BEGINNER" :)

You said "Why is 50 Ω often chosen as the input impedance of antennas, whereas the free space impedance is 377 Ω?", I think the answer is already included in the question. Yes, it's the word "INPUT". The 50 Ohm is chosen as an input not as an output impedance, if we want to transmit or receive the maximum power between the coaxial line and the antenna we have to match their impedance.(in this case is 50 Ohm because of the standards)
If you chose 377 Ohm as the input impedance of the antenna to match it to the air impedance you will lose the power transmission between the coaxial line and the antenna.
If we consider the antenna as an element of the circuit that has an input and an "output impedance" it will look as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmwLtX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The radiation resistance, \$\small R_r\$, of a half-wave dipole is \$\small 73\Omega\$. This relates directly to the feedpoint impedance, i.e. this is the impedance presented to the transmission line by the antenna at the design frequency.

\$\small R_r\$ is related to the impedance of free space (i.e. the impedance seen by an E-M wave travelling in free-space), but is not equal to it.

Comment: That's the point though: how is the radiation resistance related to the free space impedance? Alternatively, can the antenna be changed so that it is matched to the feed line but doesn't radiate its power into free space (and is lost as heat instead)?

Comment: @ahemmeter a non radiating antenna is called a dummy load.  Typically it is constructed of a resistor, at larger power capacities with careful measures to achieve cooling and manage the impedance across geometry of the element so that the SWR remains close to ideal even at higher frequencies.  You can of course add resistors in series or parallel with a real antenna, but you would probably not want to.

Comment: What this answer is missing is a statement of *why* the feedpoint impedance of a dipole is what it is.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ah, I completely forgot about the dummy load, right. So this would be an example of something that is matched to the input but not to free space anymore, since it doesn't transform any impedances.

Comment: A half-wave dipole impedance is 73 *+ 43j*. If the dipole is shortened slightly to make it _resonant_, the impedance goes down to about 70 ohms.

Comment: @Chu how would you prove/demonstrate that R_r is  related to the impedance of free space? I would say the question is also how this connection is (and I do not agree that there is such a general relation)

Comment: The radiation resistance and the feed point impedance of an antenna can be quite unrelated. The radiation resistance is simply a resistive representation of the power radiated (dissipated) by the antenna into free space.

Answer (score 0):

"...In order to efficiently deliver power to a different part of a circuit without reflection, the impedances of all circuit elements need to be matched...."

This is your **assumption**.  And it is correct, **but not in the case of antennas**.

Because in antennas, we have "reflection".  Power applied to the feed point (in a dipole, for example) travels down to the end of the wire, and is reflected back to the feed point, where (if resonant) it will meet a voltage or current 180 degrees out of phase, thus canceling, and represented by the (so-called) standing wave.

So, the applied power bounces back and forth in the antenna wire until all is radiated or lost as heat.  So it does not matter if the antenna impedance is different than free space.  What really matters, practically speaking, if the energy is reflected back into the transmitter and warms the final amp device, thus wasting the power/energy appliled.  This happens when the impedance of the final amp does not match the antenna system (transmission line plus antenna).  But once the antenna system is matched to the transmitter, almost all the energy will be transmitted to free space (except for resistance in the wire, which is usually negligible.  Or so I am told.

And to comment on the answer by Laurin Cavender WB4IVG:  In theory, there is no difference between theory and practice.

Comment: That's an interesting thought! How does it account for the fact that the same antenna in different surrounding media (different \$Z_0\$) behaves differently? As in optics, there is still an interface that creates some kind of reflection if the impedances of both media are not equal. And it seems to me that the constructive interference (standing wave) is only determined by the properties of the antenna: material and length.

Comment: **ahemmetter**:  that's also a good question - and my thought is to consider a Yagi antenna - the driven element has power applied, but the E fields affect the reflector and director elements and affect the total impedance and radiation pattern.

Comment: Hm, in a Yagi antenna the different induced waves from the passive elements are just superimposed in the far field, but not in the active part of the antenna itself. They change the radiation pattern no doubt, but is the output impedance also different?

Comment: "This happens when the impedance of the final amp does not match the antenna system (transmission line plus antenna)." is not correct. If the output impedance of the source (transmitter) matches the characteristic impedance of the transmission line (only) then there is no "re-reflection" back to the load. Otherwise there is a partial or total "re-reflection" towards the load.

Answer (score 0):

All this is good in theory but what works in practice is a different story. I  have been a communications engineer for the better part of 50 years. What we have to keep in mind here is we are attempting to explain a device called an antenna and why it does or does not work, or how well it does or does not do its job. Yes a new student can usually make a functional device from all these calculations,  however that is not always true. I have built some very exacting antennas from theory that simply performed very poorly if at all. A good example is the J pole the performance is often not at all what one would expect even if when hooked up to very fancy antenna test equipment i.e. VNA's, it looks like it should be a great radiator and receptor when in fact it was more of a dummy load. Practice and theory often don't intersect. 50 ohms has been mentioned, yes it is a great compromise between the worlds of 37.5 and 73 ohms and it works well for that, in fact 50 was chosen because it worked in practice and it was easy to build from existing materials. In particular 1/2 inch water pipe inserting insulators and a center conductor for use on US Navy ships for WWII. Isolation had to be had for the feedlines to go from the antennas on deck to the equipment located within the safety of the ship. Before WWII there were literally Shacks "Radio Shacks" and I don't mean the defunct electronics stores, built right out on the main deck so as to be able to conduct the antennas to the radios. Even in the newer (at the time) ships the radio room was built on the main deck on an outside wall. Now for obvious safety reasons in a war ship the radio room should never be on deck or easily exposed to enemy fire, equipment and personal safety was a must so coax was born. Yes there were theoretical applications before that but not in general practice, there was shielded wire in use but it was not coaxial nor did it need to be, but to conduct signals from above deck to below deck and vice versa a different feedline than twinlead or ladder line was needed, both to protect the signals coming and going but also to protect the personnel and other things like gunpowder from the RF. Antennas are much the same. I often see mention of 1/4 wave antennas mentioned, truth is there really is no such thing. Nearly all practical antennas are some sort of 1/2 wave dipole. In the case of the 1/4 wave the other half of the antennas is usually the car or some other ground plane. As for 377 ohms to 50 or any other impedance it is all about feed point and or literal angle of the antenna, such as the "V" antenna mentioned earlier. Take for example a 1/2 wave end fed antenna it needs somewhere between a 9:1 to a 12:1 Balun Transformer to make it match and work. As does the Off Center Fed Dipole. Now there is that magical and sometimes nasty word BalUn! It is very simply nothing bad or magical it is simply a matching transformer. Often used to go from a balanced feedline or antenna to a unbalanced feedline or antenna! Does the transformer know balanced from unbalanced, NO it does not. In fact it does not even know what the impedance is, it only knows ratios i.e. 1 to 1, 4 to 1 or 9 to 1. Again I point out practice is not THEORY, thousands upon thousands of 4:1 Baluns are in use all over the world matching 50 ohm devices (Radios) and feedlines usually coax to 300 400 and even 600 ohm antennas. Do they work, fantastically they do, are they text book correct, not on your life, but then again all this would be moot if it did not work in practice! So quit worrying about the numbers being correct they are at best guidelines, what works, WORKS! Besides 377 ohms is theoretical freespace and just like isotropic Virginia It Simply Does Not Exist!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So you're saying impedance matching to free space is not necessary in practice? That seems to be the case, but the question was for what reason that is not an issue. I see from practice and Maxwell's equations that all power is radiated from an antenna if it is matched to the transmission line. But nevertheless, there is an impedance mismatch between two components, and that causes a reflection at a very basic physical level (not just some simplified model). So why do we *not* need to consider it here? Does the model break down for antennas? Are they transformers?

Comment: Antennas Can be considered transformers of a type. In fact some are in to the Magnetic relm such as the Single Turn small Magnetic Loop. RF is transformed into RF Fields i.e. E and H or into Magnetic Field in the case of the Magnetic Loop antenna. So yes I would say they can be called a transformer of a type.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, @Laurin. Paragraph breaks have been around for more than 50 years. Use 2 x <Enter> to break your wall of text into logical blocks. It will help legibility greatly.